# What does "Though few, if any," mean?

Tags: grammar, idioms

> Casting a furtive glance over his shoulder, the miscreant slipped out
> the main prison gate, his slovenly appearance unnoticed in the Britsh
> fog. **Though few, if any,**  figures in mainstream media made untoward
> remarks about the penal system, the plethora of escapes from
> supposedly secure prisons embarrassed the asinine wardens.

I cannnot understand what **Though few, if any,** and sentences following the idiom means.
I imagine like this.

he rarely shows up mainstream media and
he rarely makes untoward remarks about the penal system.
Although, the plethora of escapes from supposedly secure prisons embarrassed the asinine wardens

In this case, does **Though few, if any,** mean that It is very rare that it will happen?

Comment: I found this sentence from english learning book I bought.
"1100 Words You Need to Know + Online Practice: Build Your Vocabulary in just 15 minutes a day!"

Comment: I want to make an effort by this book to understand the good and bad of English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "Though few, if any, figures" which you should Parse.

The Parsing is "Though [few, if any], figures".

Here we may take :

> "few, if any" = "some small number including Zero"

Here is one way to look at the Situation :

> SENTENCE 1 : **Few, if any, figures in mainstream media** made untoward remarks about the penal system.

Here we may take :

> "figures in mainstream media" == "Journalists, Publishers, NewsAnchors Etc"

Meaning of SENTENCE 1 :

> Very few Journalist have [ OR no Journalist has ] made remarks about the Penal System.

Even then, "the plethora of escapes [did] embarrass the asinine wardens"

Put all these together into one long sentence, we get :

> SENTENCE 2 : Though [[ few, if any, figures in mainstream media made untoward remarks about the penal system ]] , the plethora of escapes [did] embarrass the asinine wardens

Concise Meaning of SENTENCE 2 :

> Even though nobody is complaining, the wardens are embarrassed by Prison Escapes

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis.
I never had the perspective of separating "Though" and "few, if any" until you taught me.

Answer (score 1):

You are partly right. The sentence that is puzzling you doesn't refer to 'him' (the prison escapee) at all. You don't give the source of the quotation, so the connection between the two sentences isn't clear.

The writer says that very few people have made criticisms of the penal system in the mainstream media - maybe none at all. Even so, the prison authorities are embarrassed by the large number of escapes from 'secure' prisons.

Comment: thanks! I could understand that the sentence that is puzzling me refers to people in mainstream media.